# SDL Web 8 and DXA 1.4 (Java version), Content service causes error

Tags: content-delivery, dxa, web8

I'm installing SDL Web 8 (hotfix_8.1.1.1957) and DXA 1.4 (Java version).

I installed following serviced.

- Discovery
- Deployer
- Content
- Preview

Also import DXA 1.4 to Content Manager, and deploy Web application.

When I request DXA Web application's URL, Content service cause following error.

```
2016-06-29 07:28:22,504 DEBUG RequirementUtil - Claim value: cd required: cd condition met: true
2016-06-29 07:28:22,504 DEBUG RequirementUtil - Claim value: cd required: cd condition met: true
2016-06-29 07:28:22,504 DEBUG RequirementUtil - OR Operator, all claims met: true
2016-06-29 07:28:22,504 DEBUG RequirementUtil - OR Operator, all claims met: true
2016-06-29 07:28:22,504 DEBUG DefaultRulesEvaluator - Rule evaluation finished: DefaultRuleEvalResult{allowed=true, message=''}
2016-06-29 07:28:22,504 DEBUG DefaultRulesEvaluator - Rule evaluation finished: DefaultRuleEvalResult{allowed=true, message=''}
2016-06-29 07:28:22,504 DEBUG ReadWriteFilter - Rules were evaluated, access allowed to resource: GET: http://10.0.1.98:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetPreviewServerConfigurationFunctionImport
2016-06-29 07:28:22,504 DEBUG ReadWriteFilter - Rules were evaluated, access allowed to resource: GET: http://10.0.1.98:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetPreviewServerConfigurationFunctionImport
2016-06-29 07:28:22,505 DEBUG ODataServiceImpl - Handling request: GET http://10.0.1.98:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetPreviewServerConfigurationFunctionImport
2016-06-29 07:28:22,506 DEBUG ODataParserImpl - Parsing URI: http://10.0.1.98:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetPreviewServerConfigurationFunctionImport
2016-06-29 07:28:22,508 DEBUG ODataMessageRouter - Sending error message for exception:
com.sdl.odata.api.parser.ODataUriParseException: `?' expected but `G' found
        at com.sdl.odata.parser.ODataUriParser.parseUri(ODataUriParser.scala:34) ~[odata_parser-2.0.5-1003.jar:2.0.5-1003]
        at com.sdl.odata.parser.ODataParserImpl.parseUri(ODataParserImpl.java:37) ~[odata_parser-2.0.5-1003.jar:2.0.5-1003]
        at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataParserActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataParserActor.scala:34) ~[odata_service-2.0.5-20160308.014733-23.jar:2.0.5-SNAPSHOT]
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataParserActor.aroundReceive(ODataParserActor.scala:27) ~[odata_service-2.0.5-20160308.014733-23.jar:2.0.5-SNAPSHOT]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
2016-06-29 07:28:22,508 ERROR ODataRendererActor - Invalid request - com.sdl.odata.api.parser.ODataUriParseException: '`?' expected but `G' found'
com.sdl.odata.api.parser.ODataUriParseException: `?' expected but `G' found
        at com.sdl.odata.parser.ODataUriParser.parseUri(ODataUriParser.scala:34) ~[odata_parser-2.0.5-1003.jar:2.0.5-1003]
        at com.sdl.odata.parser.ODataParserImpl.parseUri(ODataParserImpl.java:37) ~[odata_parser-2.0.5-1003.jar:2.0.5-1003]
        at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataParserActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataParserActor.scala:34) ~[odata_service-2.0.5-20160308.014733-23.jar:2.0.5-SNAPSHOT]
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataParserActor.aroundReceive(ODataParserActor.scala:27) ~[odata_service-2.0.5-20160308.014733-23.jar:2.0.5-SNAPSHOT]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

dxa.stdout.log is following

```
06:58:50.757 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.w.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - doFilter: contextPath=/jp, sessionId=9F25C38152E7D1C271F7B88A23185BE7
06:58:50.758 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.JavaClaimStore@14de0303, thread: http-nio-8080-exec-20
06:58:50.758 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.claimstore.DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:uri, value=/jp/
06:58:50.758 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.claimstore.DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:full_url, value=http://54.238.137.132:55289/jp/
06:58:50.758 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.claimstore.DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:headers, value={accept-language=[Ljava.lang.String;@2f7238e7, cookie=[Ljava.lang.String;@6bcb9a3d, upgrade-insecure-requests=[Ljava.lang.String;@6513c857, host=[Ljava.lang.String;@13119ed, connection=[Ljava.lang.String;@3fbabc2c, x-forwarded-for=[Ljava.lang.String;@817c394, cache-control=[Ljava.lang.String;@73bde3b1, accept-encoding=[Ljava.lang.String;@7a4a725a, user-agent=[Ljava.lang.String;@107beae3, accept=[Ljava.lang.String;@26c6901b, via=[Ljava.lang.String;@3a7a5f19}
06:58:50.758 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.claimstore.DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:parameters, value={CONTENT_LENGTH=[Ljava.lang.String;@130b22ae, QUERY_STRING=[Ljava.lang.String;@5c68eede, CONTENT_TYPE=[Ljava.lang.String;@4e3cfb00, PATH_INFO=[Ljava.lang.String;@2656f749}
06:58:50.758 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.claimstore.DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:server:variables, value={SERVER_PORT=55289, REMOTE_HOST=210.249.69.222, SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1, DOCUMENT_ROOT=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/jp/, REQUEST_METHOD=GET, SCRIPT_NAME=/, REMOTE_ADDR=210.249.69.222, SECURE=false, PATH_TRANSLATED=null, SERVER_NAME=54.238.137.132, AUTH_TYPE=null, REMOTE_USER=null}
06:58:50.758 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.claimstore.DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:cookies, value={L%3A8D7CED9162A16FE162A16FE=1041, L%3A132FC845=1033, L%3A29640817EF75D462162A16FE=1041, L%3A5FA51DC1162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A296408178886D955162A16FE=1033, L%3A2964081777840D69162A16FE=1041, L%3A296408173A89275162A16FE=1033, L%3A63F9E4D7=1033, L%3A296408171D3B2060162A16FE=1041, L%3AADFADA9162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A2A573CE3162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A296408172390FB33162A16FE=1033, L%3AC551D817=1041, L%3A462AB3E843CFFDADA015855=1033, L%3AD9E41B6B162A16FE162A16FE=1041, L%3A59B5B3133A89275DA015855=1041, L%3A166DE05B8F332CFC7537A791=1041, L%3A30B2339C162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A2C9285DB162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3AACD2FDB7=1033, L%3AC2D80907=1041, L%3A59ECF6FE162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3AC964095=1041, L%3A513B56EB162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A59B5B3131D3B2060DA015855=1041, L%3ABFF48D8713BA30EE90FCD384=1041, L%3A8CC4AD34=1041, L%3A5E3F9FF013BA30EE13BA30EE=1041, L%3AAF2BECA8345A5E5A162A16FE=1033, L%3A72C17AB5=1041, L%3A2964081713BA30EE162A16FE=1041, L%3A1DD76369162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A29640817DB7357B9162A16FE=1033, L%3A1BFE31D87BAEC79D0E2C0B=1033, splunkweb_csrf_token_8000=5574511711683388386, L%3A5B61D1CB162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3AE7795E5B162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A29640817D9442B9E162A16FE=1041, L%3A366BA97F=1033, L%3A4A385E55162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A1ABFB3F7=1041, L%3A982D19C91D3B2060DA015855=1041, L%3AAA91C1EB2390FB33A57C4DEE=1033, L%3A3FACB0F7=1041, L%3A296408178F332CFC162A16FE=1041, L%3A81244197DB7357B9332948A5=1041, _ga=GA1.4.128284973.1435713659, L%3A25060289=1033, L%3A166DE05B13BA30EE24229BBC=1041, L%3A2964081743CFFDA162A16FE=1033, L%3AF289BA0A43CFFDA564EC989=1033, L%3A3BBF00A9=1041, L%3AA03F803B162A16FE162A16FE=1033, JSESSIONID=9F25C38152E7D1C271F7B88A23185BE7, L%3AFB7EC0D68F332CFC7537A791=1041, L%3A96ACC9F2162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A29640817345A5E5A162A16FE=1033, L%3A982D19C93A89275DA015855=1033, L%3A29640817F5DB0DBA162A16FE=1041, L%3A6F6E433F=1041, L%3A5C17F183162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3AF05C2B1E3A89275BE00D17F=1033, L%3AC88E5E07162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A4BD51BF6162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3AF4B982B1162A16FE162A16FE=1033, TAFTrackingId=tridion_cec56811-6e4f-4f52-920c-af44153088f9, L%3AB7CF2684162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A64E4C802162A16FE162A16FE=1041, L%3AFA40E91C162A16FE162A16FE=1041, L%3A63A6C82E=1033, L%3A65B3C677=1033, L%3A64E4C80213BA30EE24229BBC=1041, L%3A3662517943CFFDA6516464B=1033, L%3A7F30DF17F5DB0DBA294F0A40=1041, LPVID=BF64TNvDScGGg-sd3nvEVw, L%3AB1E9845D162A16FE162A16FE=1041, L%3AC86725803A89275DA015855=1041, L%3AD4543FF5=1033, L%3AJS=1033, L%3A45B382CDDB7357B9E8FE817=1041, L%3A79B7CEFCDB7357B9CEA1A8E4=1041, L%3A75A2EA09162A16FE162A16FE=1033, TAFSessionId=tridion_bc914550-11ec-4610-b66c-8f6cfcb97e10, L%3A554EC2D2D87BAEC7BBC46507=1033, L%3A29640817D87BAEC7162A16FE=1033, L%3A29640817FCB3218162A16FE=1041, L%3A885E02F1=1033, L%3AE741B62EEF75D4627BDA4195=1041, L%3AF9971ADBDB7357B9DCAA88DA=1041, __utma=79514384.128284973.1435713659.1461065295.1462861136.76, L%3AAFA3D418162A16FE162A16FE=1033, __utmz=79514384.1449733364.72.2.utmcsr, L%3AFB8434A9162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3AB34C0079162A16FE162A16FE=1041, L%3AD7FC3302162A16FE162A16FE=1041, L%3AA4E015D1162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3AF9F4C60B162A16FE162A16FE=1033, L%3A29640817DF7D3B9C162A16FE=1041, __atuvc=19%7C33, L%3AAADDD8A3=1041, L%3A764EB183A89275DA015855=1041}
06:58:50.758 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] INFO  c.t.a.w.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Requested by IP: /210.249.69.222
06:58:50.758 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.claimstore.DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:id, value=tridion_bc914550-11ec-4610-b66c-8f6cfcb97e10
06:58:50.758 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.claimstore.DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:tracking:id, value=tridion_cec56811-6e4f-4f52-920c-af44153088f9
06:58:50.758 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.claimstore.DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:attributes, value={}
06:58:50.759 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.w.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Processing cookie claims.
06:58:50.759 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.t.a.w.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Cookie forwarding is enabled: false
06:58:50.759 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.web.content.client.ContentClient - ForwardedClaims is configured. Will forward following claims: [taf:session:preview:preview_session]
06:58:50.773 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.o.c.caller.BasicEndpointCaller - Request ended with 201 status code.
06:58:50.775 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.o.c.m.AtomEntityUnmarshaller - Unmarshalling entity for query: ActionImportClientQuery[RequestStartActionImport]
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.w.a.client.ClaimsLegacyConverter - Could not find claim value of class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap type for uri taf:claim:context:browser:version.
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.w.a.client.ClaimsLegacyConverter - Could not find claim value of class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap type for uri taf:claim:context:browser:cssVersion.
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.w.a.client.ClaimsLegacyConverter - Could not find claim value of class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap type for uri taf:claim:context:browser:jsVersion.
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.w.a.client.ClaimsLegacyConverter - Could not find claim value of class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap type for uri taf:claim:context:device:version.
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.w.a.client.ClaimsLegacyConverter - Could not find claim value of class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap type for uri taf:claim:context:os:version.
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.DefaultClaimStore@6c82bf7f, thread: http-nio-8080-exec-20
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.web.preview.filter.ContentFilter - Processing request for '/jp/'.
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.web.preview.filter.ContentFilter - Raw URL: http://54.238.137.132:55289/jp/.
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.web.preview.filter.ContentFilter - Real path: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/jp/.
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.web.preview.filter.ContentFilter - Root path: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/jp.
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.w.p.filter.PageContentFilter - Full URL: 'http://54.238.137.132:55289/jp/'
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.w.p.filter.PageContentFilter - Real path: '/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/jp/'
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.w.p.filter.PageContentFilter - Root path: '/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/jp'
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.w.p.filter.PageContentFilter - Virtual path: 'null'
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.w.c.client.cache.CacheProvider - Cache Manager URI jar:file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/jp/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-2.8.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
06:58:50.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.w.c.client.cache.CacheProvider - Returning existing cache org.ehcache.jcache.JCache@629e7194
06:58:50.777 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.web.content.client.ContentClient - ForwardedClaims is configured. Will forward following claims: [taf:session:preview:preview_session]
06:58:50.777 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.odata.client.DefaultODataClient - Getting entity for query ODataClientQuery[GetPreviewServerConfigurationFunctionImport]
06:58:50.777 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.o.c.caller.BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: http://10.0.1.98:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetPreviewServerConfigurationFunctionImport
06:58:50.783 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.s.o.c.caller.BasicEndpointCaller - Request ended with 400 status code.
06:58:50.783 [http-nio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG c.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: null, thread: http-nio-8080-exec-20
```

I checked manual again and again, but I couldn't find what is missing.

What does cause this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: Weird! What is in the log file of your DXA Web App?

Comment: Some logs are output to dxa.stdout.log, but no error was found. I paste the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to occur in the CD ContentFilter which is used for XPM Session Preview.

This CD ContentFilter is only needed if you have Pages and/or Binaries stored on filesystem. since DXA gets everything from the CD Content Store, this CD Filter should not be needed, so a simple work-around for this problem could be to simply not use the filter at all.

For DXA 1.4, I think you can disable the filter in `web.xml`.

Comment: BTW: did you install the Session-Enabled Content Service?  An (XPM enabled) Staging Web App requires a Session-Enabled Content Service.

Comment: I removed PageContentFilter and BinaryContentFilter from `web.xml` temporary, then this error disapeared. I'll install Session-Enabled Content Service later. But another problems occurs now. I post new question about it, because It's different issue.

Comment: My new post is following. http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15027/publicationmapping-error-occurs-on-dxa-1-4-java-version-sdl-web-8